# Where do i put variables when i deploy to environments in Yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to use environments to deploy code to different environments. When i ommit the variables it works ok but soon as i put variables in it gives these errors?

Unexpected value 'environment'
Unexpected value 'strategy'

```
     stage: Development
  condition: and(succeeded('Build'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
  - deployment :
    variables:
      - name: appname
        value: testapp
  displayName: deploy Development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  environment: 'development'
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
        - script: echo Development Environment
        - template: templates/release.yml #Run Release Template
```

Comment: YAML is whitespace sensitive. The error is likely related to indentation. If the indentation present in your question is what's present in your YAML file, it's clearly incorrect. I'd recommend starting with a YAML linter and formatter and also reviewing the documentation carefully

Answer (score 1):

From your YAML sample, it should be missing an indent from displayname field, thus causing a problem with the yaml format.

You can refer to the sample below:

```
stages:
 - stage: Development
   condition: and(succeeded('Build'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
   jobs:
   - deployment :
     variables:
      - name: appname
        value: testapp
     displayName: deploy Development
     pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
     environment: 'development'
     strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
       runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
```